# How to set a secure Firebase realtime database rules for users which store by ChildByAutoId

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am confuse to setting Real-time database rules for the Users which have to alloe read adn write on own data.

Following is the structure at firebase real-time database of User Table.

[image]

And by expand it developer store the same Id "-M6njMhm89adfadfd" under the "id" key as following screenshot.

[image]

I try to check and read firebase doc all about rules. I feel the developer did mistake he use **childByAutoId** which you can see in screenshot but i am confuse how do I rules it as normal based on auth.uid.

I am followed this firebase doc : https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth

Here are i setting up rules which is not working obvious as i don;t what i set to validate the autoID (-M6njm84923945) that id i mean.

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "Layouts":{
      ".indexOn": ["r"]
    },
    "AppData": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    },
    "Users": {
      "$id":{
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($userId)
      //  ".write": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",
        ".read": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
      },
      
    }

  } 
}
```

Here are the users database json data:

```
"Users": {
    "-M6njMh3454xboHh8aaY": {
      "createdBy": "-M6njMh3454xboHh8aaY",
      "createdOn": data change ,
      "deviceId": "data change ",
      "email": "cdadfad6@gmail.com",
      "fcmToken": "",
      "id": "-M6njMh3454xboHh8aaY",
      "isBlocked": false,
      "isEmailVerified": true,
      "loginType": "FACEBOOK",
      "modifiedBy": "-M6njMh3454xboHh8aaY",
      "modifiedOn": 452345245,
      "name": "ABC CC",
      "platform": "iOS",
      "profilePicUrl": [
        "http://graph.facebook.com/452435/picture?type=large"
      ],
      "subscriptionStatus": true,
      "userId": "243523452454"
    },
    "-M6nw4AznzdfadfU-ni_9": {
      "createdBy": "-M6nw4AznzdfadfU-ni_9",
      "createdOn": 45234535,
      "deviceId": "2452345",
      "email": "asdff@wfadf.com",
      "fcmToken": "",
      "id": "-M6nw4AznzdfadfU-ni_9",
      "isBlocked": false,
      "loginType": "GOOGLE",
      "modifiedBy": "-M6nw4AznzdfadfU-ni_9",
      "modifiedOn": 245245234,
      "name": "ad dfdf",
      "platform": "iOS",
      "profilePicUrl": [
        "https://lh4.dfd.com/-qpRNZ_oaw1k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/asdfadf/dfd/photo.jpg"
      ],
      "subscriptionStatus": true
    },
```

=== Code snip ===

```
func handleLogin(_ loginModel: LoginModel, blockCompletedWith: @escaping blockCompletedWith) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: loginModel.email, password: loginModel.password) { [weak self] authResult, error in
            guard let authResult = authResult else {
                blockCompletedWith(false, "ID_INVALID_PASSWORD".localized)
                return
            }
            
            let user = authResult.user
            guard user.isEmailVerified else {
                blockCompletedWith(false, "VERIFY_EMAIL_ADDRESS".localized)
                return
            }
            
            guard let ref = self else {
                blockCompletedWith(false, "ID_SERVER_ERROR_MSG".localized)
                return
            }

            ref.getUserData(loginModel, blockCompletedWith: blockCompletedWith)
        }
    }
    
    func loginWithEmail(email: String, password: String, blockCompletedWith: @escaping blockCompletedWith) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] authResult, error in
            guard let authResult = authResult else {
                blockCompletedWith(false, "ID_INVALID_PASSWORD".localized)
                return
            }
            
            let user = authResult.user
            
            print("\(user)and \(user.uid)")
            
            guard user.isEmailVerified else {
                blockCompletedWith(false, "VERIFY_EMAIL_ADDRESS".localized)
                return
            }
            
            guard let ref = self else {
                blockCompletedWith(false, "ID_SERVER_ERROR_MSG".localized)
                return
            }
            blockCompletedWith(true, "Success")
        }
    }
    
    func getUserData(_ loginModel: LoginModel, blockCompletedWith: @escaping blockCompletedWith) {
        let query: DatabaseQuery = usersNodeRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: loginModel.email)
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if let data = dict.values.first{
                    let json = JSON(data)
                    
                    print("\(json)")
                    
                    _USER_INFO.setProfileData(json: json, isSaveInPref: true)
                    blockCompletedWith(true, "ID_SUCCESS_MESSAGE".localized)
                }
            }
            else {
                blockCompletedWith(false, "LOGIN_FAILED".localized)
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            blockCompletedWith(false, "\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as i clearly write i can't able to understand the rules as per database there are use childByAutoID you can see ids. Now the confustion is what should i set the rules based on autoID? let me add the rules here which is not allow to user logged in

Comment: As i can;t change the autoId to UID is there are lots of user already registered and that done by old developer who store Users data like that. I just want to restrict database which Logged in user can access read and write only own data not able to other's data read or write and i want to write rules for that with this structure if you can help me @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: `".read": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"` Is there a `uid` child in your data with the correct value? It's more likely we can help if you: 1) show us only the relevant data as JSON text, rather than a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) Show us the code that isn't working the against the rules and data.

Comment: Alright i added json users data. Due to security i change the value of email or other but this is the data in users table @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thanks, and indeed: one of the advantages of posting as text is that you can change values and remove irrelevant data. :) Can you also show the code that isn't working against these rules and data?

Comment: First thing I note btw is that your rules check against a child node names `uid`, while the data has a child node named `userId`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen main old developer store social media id as userId and if this is normal email then that filed black. I have to setting rules based on the main parent node which his : M6nw4AznzdfadfU-ni_9

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to read from the `/Users` node here:

```
let query: DatabaseQuery = usersNodeRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: loginModel.email)
```

But looking at your rules, nobody is granted permission to read from `/Users`, so this read is rejected. Keep in mind that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#rules-not-filters) and instead merely ensure that the code only accesses data it's authorized for.

---

If you want anyone to be able to read the `/Users` node, you can do so by:

```
"Users": {
  ".read": true
},
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on owner-only access.

---

If you want the user to be allowed to query `/Users`, as long as they specify their own email address, that'd be:

```
"Users": {
  ".read": "query.orderByChild === 'email' &&
            query.equalTo === auth.token.email"
},
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules).

---

Comment: Let me check impliments that and will let you know soon. Thanks for your time

Comment: I do have one question what if the validate with social Media account? speciallly with apple id logged in which some user hide thier email is this work same.

I just wanted to restrict logged in user can not able to read or write other's email and their data

Comment: That's why you should use the UID to check. For an example of this, see the Firebase documentation on [securing content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).